# AWS EKS no tiller pod found but helm install is working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I read that to use Helm I need to install Tiller to my cluster. But I tried to install my release using helm and it succeed, even though there is no Tiller pod in my EKS cluster. The pods I found in the namespace "kube-system" are:

aws-node
coredns
kube-proxy

Do I need it or I miss something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the helm version.Tiller was necessary in Helm 2 but Helm 3 does not have tiller. Check the [announcement blog](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-preview-pt2/).

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. So helm 2 will be unable to communicate with kube cluster if there is not Tiller am I right?